# "invalid option" error when running cucumber with "--tags"

Tags: cucumber, capybara, testunit

I've been playing around with Cucumber for about three weeks now, and everything works well, except this little thing here.

Whenever I run my tests with e.g. `cucumber checkout.feature --tags @monthly`, I get the following on my console after the test have run successfully:

```
invalid option: --tags
Test::Unit automatic runner.
Usage: /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/cucumber [options] [-- untouched arguments]
    -r, --runner=RUNNER              Use the given RUNNER.
                                     (c[onsole], e[macs], x[ml])
        --collector=COLLECTOR        Use the given COLLECTOR.
                                     (de[scendant], di[r], l[oad], o[bject]_space)
    -n, --name=NAME                  Runs tests matching NAME.
                                     (patterns may be used).
        --ignore-name=NAME           Ignores tests matching NAME.
                                     (patterns may be used).
    -t, --testcase=TESTCASE          Runs tests in TestCases matching TESTCASE.
                                     (patterns may be used).
        --ignore-testcase=TESTCASE   Ignores tests in TestCases matching TESTCASE.
                                     (patterns may be used).
        --location=LOCATION          Runs tests that defined in LOCATION.
                                     LOCATION is one of PATH:LINE, PATH or LINE
        --attribute=EXPRESSION       Runs tests that matches EXPRESSION.
                                     EXPRESSION is evaluated as Ruby's expression.
                                     Test attribute name can be used with no receiver in EXPRESSION.
                                     EXPRESSION examples:
                                       !slow
                                       tag == 'important' and !slow
        --[no-]priority-mode         Runs some tests based on their priority.
        --default-priority=PRIORITY  Uses PRIORITY as default priority
                                     (h[igh], i[mportant], l[ow], m[ust], ne[ver], no[rmal])
    -I, --load-path=DIR[:DIR...]     Appends directory list to $LOAD_PATH.
        --color-scheme=SCHEME        Use SCHEME as color scheme.
                                     (d[efault])
        --config=FILE                Use YAML fomat FILE content as configuration file.
        --order=ORDER                Run tests in a test case in ORDER order.
                                     (a[lphabetic], d[efined], r[andom])
        --max-diff-target-string-size=SIZE
                                     Shows diff if both expected result string size and actual result string size are less than or equal SIZE in bytes.
                                     (1000)
    -v, --verbose=[LEVEL]            Set the output level (default is verbose).
                                     (important-only, n[ormal], p[rogress], s[ilent], v[erbose])
        --[no-]use-color=[auto]      Uses color output
                                     (default is auto)
        --progress-row-max=MAX       Uses MAX as max terminal width for progress mark
                                     (default is auto)
        --no-show-detail-immediately Shows not passed test details immediately.
                                     (default is yes)
        --output-file-descriptor=FD  Outputs to file descriptor FD
        --                           Stop processing options so that the
                                     remaining options will be passed to the
                                     test.
    -h, --help                       Display this help.

Deprecated options:
        --console                    Console runner (use --runner).
```

I probably didn't need to put all of that here, but I wanted to give you an impression of how much text appears on my screen after each test, which can be a bit distracting.

Here is my setup:

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "rspec"
gem "cucumber"

gem "capybara"
gem "capybara-webkit"

gem "selenium"
gem "selenium-client"
gem "selenium-webdriver"
```

**env.rb**

```
require_relative '../../../config.rb'

require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Capybara.app_host = AT_ROOT
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
Capybara.default_wait_time = DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = IGNORE_HIDDEN_ELEMENTS

# Define window size of the browser here
Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(DEFAULT_WINDOW_HEIGHT, DEFAULT_WINDOW_WIDTH)
```

I couldn't find any connection to the `Test::Unit automatic runner` in the console output, but apparently it's got something to do with it.

Do you have any idea what that could be? I found some threads related to this issue, but they didn't help me unfortunately.

Thank you

Comment: Which version of Cucumber and Bundler do you use?

Comment: Cucumber: 1.2.1
Bundler: 1.3.0

Comment: Cucumber [supports Ruby 2.0 only from 1.2.2](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/blob/master/History.md)

Comment: Thank you, @AndreyBotalov. Didn't know that. Surprisingly, everything has been working smoothly, but will update soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
cucumber features -t @monthly
```